# header('Location: not REDIRECT but RELOAD body to body of target file

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect page (index.php) to new url (user.php) after logging in.

after I verify users data from my form I want to redirect user to new file called user.php

and I use for that:

```
         header("Location: user.php");
```

after that page doesn't redirect but reload body content to content of user.php
so user is still on index.php and user.php doesn't work properly.

It's appears only on my new server.

I tested it on koding.io and it was ok.

I tried to use

```
ob_start();
```

and

```
ob_end_flush();
```

but it does not work

thank you for answers

Comment: Are your server sending '302 Found' header?

Comment: yes index.php has status code: 302 and then user.php 200

Comment: Are there any `Headers already sent` warnings in the PHP error log?

Comment: no there aren't ... ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header("Location: user.php");
exit;
```

Be sure that your PHP code does not output any response before this otherwise you will receive headers already sent message.

Answer (score 0):

i got answer for my question!

problem was with jQuery mobile which I use here...

"In jQuery Mobile, form submissions are automatically handled using Ajax whenever possible..."

I had to add data-ajax="false"  to my form:

```
<form  data-ajax="false" action="php/login.php" method="post">
```

and this does the job!!!

Thank you for help!